# Apache, PHP, WordPress caching issue in Docker container

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching, docker

I'm on OS X using the Virtualbox driver for docker. Using the official [WordPress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) docker image, I setup a volume from my local machine to map to the container

`/Users/gezimhome/projects/zr/src`:`/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/zr`

**When I update files in the host, they show updated in the container but changes don't reflect on the website** until a few minutes later. I suspect it might be Apache caching something as I don't have any  WordPress caching plugins installed.

**Update**: I've not tried other types of files. The PHP files are not being updated when I load the site in the browser (or even using `curl`).

**Update 2**: Here's the [.htaccess](http://dpaste.com/278J2H4) file.
Here's the [docker virtualbox info](http://dpaste.com/0RZ3HMA)

Comment: specifically what kind of files

Comment: Thanks for asking. PHP files.

Comment: Are there any issues with your port mappings? Have you checked your .htaccess file for any weird headers?

Comment: Also what's the config on the docker container in question? Have you allocated resources correctly? Enough RAM / CPU?

Comment: Updated with more info, @MatthewRath.

Comment: very odd, can you get the log of what happens when you copy / change a file?

Comment: Nothing shows up in docker logs when I change a file, @MatthewRath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103019/discussion-between-gezim-and-matthew-rath).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) in PHP. Opcache was enabled in the [wordpress docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/df190dc9c5752fd09317d836bd2bdcd09ee379a5/apache/Dockerfile) as follows:

```
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=60'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
```

So, I created a new [docker image for wordpress that disables](https://hub.docker.com/r/hgezim/wp-nocache/) caching. It's essentially this:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
```

Comment: Nice find. You can also simply map a blank file over that one like:     -v ./blankopcache/opcache-recommended.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini

Comment: Thanks for this! Caching is not great while developing and there's nothing about the stack the official image uses online.

Comment: Wow that's awesome. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: You could also just add `php_flag opcache.enable Off` to your WordPress .htaccess, which disables the opcode caching.